# Iterator only gets first Element in JavaFX

Tags: java, xml, iterator, jdom-2

i am wondering why my Iterator only gets the first Element while getting trough a List from an XML reader

My XML File:

```
<Genre>
    <Name>Horror</Name>
    <Name>Action</Name>
    <Name>Kinderfilm</Name>
    <Name>Komödie</Name>
    <Name>Splatter</Name>
 </Genre>
```

My Java-Code:

```
List list = rootNode.getChildren("Genre");

System.out.println("Count Genre: " + list.size());
Iterator i = list.iterator();

while (i.hasNext()) {
   Element gen = (Element) i.next();
   String name = gen.getChildText("Name");
   System.out.println("NAME: " + name);
   genre.add(name);
}
```

It only gets one Element (Horror)

Hope someone can help me. 
Punching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `rootNode` is the root of your document, then

```
List list = rootNode.getChildren("Genre");
```

will return a list with size 1 containg the `Genre` node.

Iterating this list will of course only once run through the while body, with `gen` pointing to the `Genre` element.
Calling `gen.getChildText("Name")` on this node will return the text content of the first child element named `Name`, returning `Horror`.

What you probably want to do:

```
Element genre = rootNode.getChild("Genre");

Iterator<Element> names = genre.getChildren("Name").iterator();
while (names.hasNext()) {
     String name = names.next().getText();
     ...
}
```

Comment: I assume you meant to write `getChildren("Name")` instead of getChildren("name") and `getText()` instead of getText("Name")?

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution, (s.time i feel so f**** stupid)